# Does Paypal Android SDK support parrallel, Chained payments?

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I wonder if paypal Mobile SDKs support the Adaptive, Chained, Parallel payments. Their SDK repository does not have these details. http://paypal.github.io/. Does Paypal Support these payments?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the adaptive payments is supported as part of Classic APIs only. They are yet to be live with Rest API's.  Stay tuned for the updates.

https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby